# WinRT architecture hobbles MVVM design

Tags: mvvm, windows-runtime, datatemplate

This may be too general a question, but it's causing me some lost sleep.  Do the designers of WinRT either not understand MVVM patterns or are we supposed to be abandoning MVVM in favor of some other pattern?  They have not only removed the DataTemplate pattern (where any POCO used in an ItemsControl or ContentControl can be automatically bound to a visual tree), but they went ahead and removed the **x:Type** operator as a key into the resource dictionary (e.g. "{x:Type MyObject}").  The confusing thing here is that a DataTemplate replacement is relatively trivial (many people have done this for Silverlight), but by removing the **x:Type** operator, they've made it impossible to even write a replacement DataTemplate search in WinRT.

So my question is, why do the architects of WinRT appear to be going out of their way to prevent us from using an MVVM pattern to build applications?  Is there a better pattern that I've not yet found?

Comment: Back in 2012, I wrote a class that provides a reasonable alternative. It relies on built in support for the `DataTempateSelector`. http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1705

Comment: WiredPrairie, yes, it had occurred to me that you could decorate the name, but this comes across as a hack.  The architects of WinRT obviously know how DataTemplates work in WPF.  I'm wondering why they intentionally disabled the use of the x:Type.  I realize that there's a paradigm shift going on here, but I'm having trouble understanding the new direction that we're supposed to follow.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of opinion. I don't consider using a selector class a hack. While I used the WPF style, it's so simple to use a Selector (and actually more clear what's going on in simple cases than trying to find where in the project the correct DataTemplate is being "automatically" loaded).

Comment: I agree that there's a new mindset to this OS and I don't mind it, really.  I just don't understand what we're supposed to use if not MVVM and, if it is MVVM, I don't understand how we're supposed to build applications when the Content control is busted and the DataTemplate is hobbled.

Comment: I'd disagree that it's broken and that you can't use MVVM. Maybe the way you build them isn't like WPF -- but it's certainly possible.

Comment: If you have a working example of a working ContentControl that uses a DataTemplateSelector I would greatly appreciate it if you'd share it.  The 'item' parameter in **SelectTemplateCore** is always null when bound to a view model.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. It's just Windows Runtime isn't mature yet, since it appeared in Windows 8, the latest version of Windows operating system.

Like any new technology, it will evolve in newer versions - or we all expect that -.

Also, think that WinRT is more than just XAML and data-binding, but a new Windows API which is aimed to replace Win32, at least in modern and multi-device development, accessible both by managed environments like .NET and also unmanaged ones like C++.

Rather than saying "they want to prevent us from using MVVM" it's more "they want to switch to a new approach to create operating system components" and it's inmanture yet.

Anyway, losing some capabilities isn't abandoning MVVM in UI development, and I'm pretty sure that future Windows versions will gradually introduce new (and not that new) features.